# xlrd original value of the cell

Tags: python, excel, xls, xlrd

I'm reading xls file using xlrd. The problem is, when xlrd reading value like this **"12/09/2012"**, i get result like this **"xldate:41252.0"**. When I use **xlrd.xldate_as_tuple**, i get this result:

**(2016, 12, 10, 0, 0, 0)**

My code:

```
curr_row = -1
while curr_row < num_rows:
    curr_row += 1
    row = worksheet.row(curr_row)     
        for x in xrange(num_cols):
            field_type = worksheet.cell_type(curr_row, x)
            if field_type == 3: # this is date
                field_value = worksheet.cell_value(curr_row, x)
                print worksheet.cell(curr_row, x).value
                print xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(field_value, 1)
```

Result:

```
41252.0
(2016, 12, 10, 0, 0, 0)
```

Both results are wrong for me. How can i get original cell value "12/09/2012" using xlrd ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the [docstring](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/master/xlrd/xldate.py#L35), you should pass your workbook's datemode to `xldate_as_tuple` as a second parameter:

```
from datetime import datetime
import xlrd


book = xlrd.open_workbook("test.xls")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
a1 = sheet.cell_value(rowx=0, colx=0)

print a1  # prints 41252.0
print xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(a1, 1)  # prints (2016, 12, 10, 0, 0, 0)

a1_tuple = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(a1, book.datemode)  
print a1_tuple  # prints (2012, 12, 9, 0, 0, 0)

a1_datetime = datetime(*a1_tuple)
print a1_datetime.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")  # prints 12/09/2012
```

Comment: it helps ! but is there any way i can get original string "12/09/2012" ?